# template which accepts either a type or a template as its parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

Is it possible to have a template which accepts either a type or a template as its template parameter?

I tried the following using partial template specialization, but failed:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <template <typename...> class T>
struct TemplateHolder;

template <typename T>
struct Trait : std::true_type {};

template <template <typename...> class Template>
struct Trait<TemplateHolder<Template>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename... Ts>
struct Foo {};

struct Bar {};

static_assert(Trait<Bar>::value, "");
static_assert(Trait<Foo>::value, "");
```

**error message from GCC:**

```
main.cpp:18:24: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<class T> struct Trait'

 static_assert(Trait<Foo>::value, "");
                        ^
main.cpp:18:24: note:   expected a type, got 'Foo'
```

<kbd>[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a7da7e665dd687f4)</kbd>

Comment: No, you cannot do that.

Comment: `Trait<Foo>` won't match the specialized version, but `Trait<TemplateHolder<Foo>>` does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static_assert(Trait<TemplateHolder<Foo>>::value, "");
```

Is no longer a syntax error.  You must shove the templates into the holder yourself.

Other than that, no, what you ask for does not work.